# what is the mechansm of memory readable only ？

Tags: c, memory, constants

In generaly memory can be readable and writable.when C compiler set memory const,what is mechan of it?who block the memory being written.if by mistake to force to write the marked const memory,who is reporting the segment error?

Comment: That's part of the OS and/or underlying hardware. And trying to modify "const memory" is usually *undefined behavior*, there's no guarantee of a "segment error"

Comment: the segments of a program can be read-only or writable. The operating system places them in different pages

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit

Answer (score 2):

There is **no specified mechanism in the C11 standard for read only memory**. Check by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). But be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (e.g. writing in some `const` data).

In practice, on many C implementations running on current [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (e.g. Linux, Windows, Android, MacOSX, ...) and desktops, tablets or servers with an [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) or an [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) processor, a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) has some [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), with various segments, some being read only (and managed by the operating system [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) with the help of the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)). Read also about [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) & [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). Take several days to read a book like [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable).

On embedded [microcontrollers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) (e.g. [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/) like), some memory might be a hardware [ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory). And some compilers *might* (but are not required to!) use it for some of your constant data.

You might use [linker scripts](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html) (with GNU `ld`) to organize some read only segments into read-only memory. This is very implementation specific.

However, some platforms don't have any kind of user-programmable read-only memory (e.g. some [embedded systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system) have a factory ROM containing a fixed [boot loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting#BOOT-LOADER) in [firmware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware), and everything else is in RAM). YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

It's the operating systems which marks *pages* of *virtual memory* as either readable, writable or executable (or a combination of all).

The compiler and linker works together to mark special sections of the executable file, and then the operating system loader handles setting up the memory itself.

Nothing of this is part of the C standard, which only specifies that attempting to modify a `const` variable is undefined behavior.

Comment: some RT OS such vxworks  supporting no-mmu architecture still use const to mark some memory.if write the const meomory,the system will be suspended

Answer (score -1):

The complier and linker implement it, for instance in a embeded system, data on RAM is changable, while data on Flash/ROM is not changable.

So if the data is defined with const, it will be place into a non-volative storage place, e.g. Flash/ROM, disk.

Defining a variable with const has two benefits:
- Avoid this variable is changed by coding error.(complier error)
- Reduce RAM usage, e.g. A long text should be placed into Flash/ROM or disk.

Comment: There is absolutely no guarantee or requirement that `const` goes into ROM. This is implementation specific.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It is however industry de facto standard to use `const` for that very purpose on ROM-based system.

Comment: It really depends of your platform and implementation (compiler & linker). There is no guarantee, and you can put read-only data into RAM (e.g. with some linker script). Some systems (even embedded ones) don't have flashable ROM.

Comment: on SingleChip ，on non-OS system on code segment there are some const such as const string，if write these address，what happen？

Comment: Depends on the mico-chip, an exception/interrupt shall be raised.